# Delete 'Result' of Activity functions from History table

Tags: azure, azure-functions, serverless, azure-durable-functions

The Azure Durable Functions runtime maintains a '[History Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable-functions-checkpointing-and-replay)' to record the orchestration events. One of the columns in this table is the 'Result' column which is used to store the return value of an activity function. Activity functions could return 'sensitive' data as intermediate output.

Is there a way to clear this 'Result' after successful completion of an orchestration? Yes, also thinking GDPR :)

UPDATE: Found a relevant github issue 
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/17

Comment: This is just Table Storage, you could do it "manually" with a script or something, if you know which rows to cleanup

Comment: Agree , but this warning on that link discourages me to take that approach - 

**Warning**
While it's useful as a debugging tool, don't take any dependency on this table. It may change as the Durable Functions extension evolves.

Comment: A property on the 'DurableOrchestrationClientBase' to cleanup would be cool so that it can be set and then it just does the job